# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?android:attr

Tags: android, eclipse

Quiero aplicar una plantilla (Theme) creada por mi, y el error es cuando relaciono un textview con un puntero de atributo que se utiliza en el Theme

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="?android:attr/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="HOY QUIERO DARLE DE BEBER AL SEDIENTO"/>
```

El archivo attr.xml esta creado en la carpeta res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <!-- View styles -->
   <attr name="textTitle" format="reference" />
   <attr name="textSubtitle" format="reference" />
   <attr name="textBody" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: El error es en la siguiente linea de codigo style="?android:attr/textTitle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir un atributo de referencia debes declarar

```
<declare-styleable name="Title">
    <attr name="textTitle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="textSubtitle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="textBody" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Y para crear tu `TextView`

```
<com.tuapp.Title
 android:id="@+id/title"
 custom:textTitle="@color/my_color1"
 custom:textSubtitle="@color/my_color2"
 custom:textBody = "@color/my_color3"
 ..... />
```

**EDICIÓN**

Bueno, como sabes los atributos con `format="reference"` son como lo dice su nombre "hacer referencia" a distintos tipos de `<style>` o `layouts` ya definidos, en la pregunta que tu dejas el usuario dice que crees los `attr` (tal como te lo deje yo). Luego en el archivo define `<style>`

**style.xml**

```
<style name="small_title_text">
  <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dip</item>
</style>
```

Y luego en este mismo archivo define

```
 <style name="Theme.Small">
    <item name="textTitle">@style/small_title_text</item>
    <item name="textBody">@style/small_body_text</item>
 </style>
```

Donde dice que para el `<style>` `Theme.Small` hay un item el cual se llama `textTitle` (que es el attr que creaste) y le da `@style/small_title_text` que es la referencia tal y como esta creado en `attr.xml`

El error que tu tienes es que creaste el `attr` pero no la referencia a la cual va a obedecer.

```
<TextView  
  android:id="@+id/title" 
  style="?textTitle"  //<---- Hace referencia al Item y no al attr como piensas 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="Select the size of the text"
 />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime

Comment: Le podes dar una mirada a la respuesta con mayor puntaje? Eso es lo que quiero hacer

Comment: lo actualice @AxelStermann

Comment: Entonces esta linea la tengo que dejar como esta? style="?textTitle"

Comment: Si, tu estabas haciendo referencia style = attr y eso no es valido

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ya me funciono!